# How to avoid Google Play Game Services Login dialog auto-prompt?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

The activities of my game extends BaseGameActivity as stated in guidelines from Google Play Game Services. The problem is that when my activities are launched, a dialog for login in Google Play Services is displayed on the screen. I want to avoid it. I want to put a button on the screen for the login.

¿How can be avoided the auto prompt of the login dialog? I can't find anything in the guidelines

https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin?hl=es

https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist?hl=es#improving_the_sign_in_experience_for_games

Comment: Does your code have **mHelper.setup(listener)** or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extended BaseGameActivity, I recommend you import the **BaseGameUtils** library and use the **GameHelper** class. Eg..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GameHelper mHelper;
    private GameHelperListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);

        listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSignInSucceeded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSignInFailed() {

            }

        };
        mHelper.setup(listener);
    }
}
```

[Check out this link. You can control when google services asks to log in by controllign when setup is called](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#using_gamehelper_without_basegameactivity)

Answer (score 0):

As [Ogen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2155605/ogen) mentions in his answer, using `BaseGameUtils` is quite useful. It does require some extra work from your part, which might be worth it but it might also not be.

If you want to keep using `BaseGameActivity`, then you can add the following

```
mHelper.mConnectOnStart = false;
```

to `onCreate()` of your activity that extends `BaseGameActivity`. This will prevent auto sign-in.

Comment: did you mean mHelper.setConnectOnStart(false);

Comment: It's the same thing, but yes using the `setConnectOnStart()` accessor is probably a better idea :-)